# Is there any way to paste multiple cells at once into a table in the WP visual editor?

Tags: excel, wordpress, visual-editor

I'm setting a client loose on a pretty massive amount of content migration, and looking for a way to help them speed up the process.

They have a number of pages that display nearly identical tables of data, with only two columns of the table that differ from page to page (about 80 of these pages).  The client is not HTML savvy, and the tables are fairly complex (merged cells, etc), so I'm suggesting that they copy an example page I set up and edit just edit the columns that need to be changed out.

This works so long as they copy and paste one cell at a time, so my question: is there any way to paste multiple cells at once into a table in the WP visual editor? When we try this from excel it either replaces the entire table with the new column, or adds a new table with that column inside of a cell.  Just wondering if there's a plugin or set of tools or a better workflow that might allow us to speed this up?

Any thoughts would be appreciated, but I'm resigned to the one cell at a time method based on what I've been able to find so far.

Comment: There are table manager plugins, maybe there's one that handles imports. So the table is a CPT and it's used in pages/posts as a shortcode (preferably with an interface to do it).

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of. The visual UI in Wordpress is pretty limited, and really only allows copy/pasting similar to a Word document. Since your client isn't HTML savvy, the best course might be to have them make edits in Excel, and then copy/paste the new edit into the new Wordpress page, save, publish, move on to the next new page, repeat.